# How to easily create ordered tuples out of a list?

Tags: julia

I have some list of the from let's say `[31, 1, 30, 12, 11, 22, 29, 28, 27, 26]` and am wanted to create an ordered list of tuples like `[(31, 1), (1,30),(30,12), (12, 11), (11,22), (22,29), (29,28), (28,27), (27,26)]`. Always the middle numbers are doubled and then paired.

Answer (score 2):

Having  `a = [31, 1, 30, 12, 11, 22, 29, 28, 27, 26]` you could do:

```
julia> tuple.((@view a[1:end-1]), @view a[2:end])
9-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (31, 1)
 (1, 30)
 (30, 12)
 (12, 11)
 (11, 22)
 (22, 29)
 (29, 28)
 (28, 27)
 (27, 26)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is another option:

```
julia> using IterTools

julia> IterTools.partition(A,2,1) |> collect
9-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (31, 1)
 (1, 30)
 (30, 12)
 (12, 11)
 (11, 22)
 (22, 29)
 (29, 28)
 (28, 27)
 (27, 26)
```

Note: in many cases there will be no need to `collect` the iterator, and the iterator can just be used (e.g. in a `for` loop) for further computation. This would save some memory.